# Convex conjugate and Positive Homogeneity

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a locally convex space and let $p: X \to (-\infty,\infty]$ be a proper, lower semicontinuous and positively homogeneous function with its convex conjugate $p^*$. For $\phi \in X^*$, prove that $$p^*(\phi)<\infty \Rightarrow p^*(\phi)=0.$$

My approach was to use the defintion
$p^*(\phi)=\sup_{x\in X}(\phi(x)-p(x))$ and the Fenchel-Moreau Theorem, which states that $\forall x\in X: p(x) = \sup_{\phi \in X^*}(\phi(x)-p^*(x)),$ but I'm not sure if this is the right way and where the positive homogeneity comes into play. Would be nice if someone could help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider $X=\mathbb{R}^2 $, $p(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $\phi(x,y)=x$ then $p^*(\phi)=\frac{1}{4}$ So you have something missing in your statement at the very least.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh This function is not positively homogeneous (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity).

Comment: You mean degree 1 positive homogeneous. That wiki page details the more general notion I was referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p^*(\phi)>0$ then we have $x\in X$ such that $\phi(x)-p(x)>0$. However this means for all $t>0, \phi(tx)-p(tx)= t(\phi(x)-p(x))>0$ and letting $t\to \infty$ we then have $p^*(\phi)=\infty$

It remains to show, if for all $x\in X, \phi(x)-p(x)\leq 0$ then $p^*(\phi)=0$ Notice, for all $x\in X, t>0, \phi(tx)-p(tx)=t(\phi(x)-p(x))\leq 0$ and so letting $t\to 0$ we then have $p^*(\phi)=0$

Comment: Thank you, good explanation! :)